# Unable to allocate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing an issue where I need to read the file but instead giving me an error
"Unable to allocate 243. MiB for an array with shape (5, 6362620) and data type float64"

here are my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('D:/School/Classes/2nd Sem/Datasets/fraud.csv'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

df = pd.read_csv('D:/School/Classes/2nd Sem/Datasets/fraud.csv')
```

when i run the last line of code, it will give me an error.

PS. I am using python3 jupyter notebook, windows 10 home single language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MemoryError is coming because your file is too large in size, to solve this, you can use the **chunk-size**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:/School/Classes/2nd Sem/Datasets/fraud.csv", chunksize=1000)
```

Link for more help -
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html